# Deploying with TimeoutException errors in Jboss 7

Tags: caching, jboss7.x, infinispan

I'm deploying cluster setup with Jboss 7, but failed when adding/removing the large number (1000 enrties) of entries in Infinispan cache with exception "org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to acquire lock after":

```
2016-04-05 03:37:30,102 ERROR [transport-thread-14]-[org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] ISPN000136: Execution error: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to acquire lock after [290 seconds] on key [2y1455s-13fntc-ilxzqr13-1-im24ko61-7] for requestor [GlobalTransaction:<192.168.1.3/test-cache>:18497090:local]! Lock held by [GlobalTransaction:<192.168.1.1/test-cache>:5056802:remote]
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.lock(LockManagerImpl.java:213)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.acquireLock(LockManagerImpl.java:186)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockKeyAndCheckOwnership(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockAndRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor$LockAcquisitionVisitor.lockAndRecord(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:254)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor$LockAcquisitionVisitor.visitSingleKeyCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor$LockAcquisitionVisitor.visitRemoveCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:237)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.RemoveCommand.acceptVisitor(RemoveCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.acquireLocksVisitingCommands(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:335)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(NotificationInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptorAndVerifyTransaction(TxInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(TxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPrepareCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:126)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTopologyAffectedCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:216)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTxCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:189)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPrepareCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:126)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPrepareCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:126)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:343)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.prepare(TransactionCoordinator.java:141)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator.prepare(TransactionCoordinator.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.commit(TransactionXaAdapter.java:124)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelOnePhaseCommit(XAResourceRecord.java:667)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.onePhaseCommit(BasicAction.java:2263)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1475)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:98)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.executeCommandAndCommitIfNeeded(CacheImpl.java:1196)
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.removeInternal(CacheImpl.java:314)
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.access$600(CacheImpl.java:120)
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl$6.call(CacheImpl.java:994)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The cache configuration in standalone-full-ha.xml

```
 <cache-container name="test-cache" default-cache="security" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/test/cache" start="EAGER">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000" />
                <replicated-cache name="security" start="EAGER" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/test/cache/security" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="60000">
                    <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" acquire-timeout="290000"/>
                    <transaction mode="NON_DURABLE_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="420000"/>
                </replicated-cache>
```

Thank you

Comment: Hmmm, any chance you could try a more recent Wildfly version? e.g. Wildfly 10. Hard to say what's the cause at first glance.

Comment: It's working fine after upgrading to Wildfly. Thank you